# Want a cute word for "message showing requirements"

Tags: single-word-requests

What will be the small & cute word for "A message to show your requirement or what you want"?

I want to use that in my website.

Answer (score 5):

*[request](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/request)*:

> **request** [noun]
>
> 1 An act of asking politely or formally for something:

Certainly small enough.

Cute enough? Your call.

Comment: i want to use that in my website. so "Post a noun" doesn't sound that much good